# How to evaluate user inputs like Greater than today in LUIS and BOT Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am building a BOT using Microsoft Bot framework in C# and LUIS.
Using the prebuilt entity datetime.V2, I am able to capture terms like "last week", "next month" etc. properly.
However I am struck when it comes to:

```
 "Get me all products which has expiry life greater than 2 years",
 "greater than today",
 "> today" etc.,
```

Do I use LUIS composite entities? If so, would "Greater than" and "today" become the child for a composite entity named say, "DateComparer"?
Is there any github sample that I can refer to to understand how composite entites would be parsed?

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Comment: So what are you struggling with? Do you use composite entities right now? I trained a very simple LUIS with composite entity including datetime.V2 and a "list entity" containing keywords used for comparsion (greater, greater than). It is recognized quite ok. I can make an answer and share a LUIS json with you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Miskov.
I created a ComparerList taking your suggestion.
`  "composites": [
    {
      "name": "DateComparer",
      "children": [
        "ComparerList",
        "datetimeV2"
      ]
    }
  ],`

Comment: "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "ComparerList",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "gt",
          "list": [
            "greater than",
            "larger than",
            "more than",
            "over",
            "exceeding",
            "higher than",
            ">"
          ]
        },

Comment: I am able to train Luis to return the following json based on 
utterances like "Give me all items with expiry greater than yesterday".
And I get the following json back when testing.

Comment: "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "greater than",
      "type": "ComparerList",
      "startIndex": 33,
      "endIndex": 44,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          **"gt"**
        ]
      }
    },

Comment: From this, I retrieve the "gt" resolution and use it in my code.
Please let me know if you see something amiss.

Comment: This is a good work around, you should post it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a ComparerList taking Miskov's suggestion.

```
  "composites": [
    {
      "name": "DateComparer",
      "children": [
        "ComparerList",
        "datetimeV2"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "closedLists": [
    {
      "name": "ComparerList",
      "subLists": [
        {
          "canonicalForm": "gt",
          "list": [
            "greater than",
            "larger than",
            "more than",
            "over",
            "exceeding",
            "higher than",
            ">"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "lt",
          "list": [
            "<",
            "less than"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "eq",
          "list": [
            "=",
            "equal to"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "le",
          "list": [
            "<=",
            "less than or equal to"
          ]
        },
        {
          "canonicalForm": "ge",
          "list": [
            ">=",
            "greater than or equal to"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bing_entities": [
    "datetimeV2"
  ],
```

I am able to train Luis to return the following json based on 
utterances like "Give me all items with expiry greater than yesterday".
And I get the following json back when testing.

```
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "greater than",
      "type": "ComparerList",
      "startIndex": 33,
      "endIndex": 44,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "gt"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "greater than yesterday",
      "type": "DateComparer",
      "startIndex": 33,
      "endIndex": 54,
      "score": 0.6950233
    },
    {
      "entity": "yesterday",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
      "startIndex": 46,
      "endIndex": 54,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2017-09-14",
            "type": "date",
            "value": "2017-09-14"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

From this, I retrieve the "gt" resolution and use it in my code.

Comment: This should be fine for you, although the score is somehow low. Remember, that the list entity looks for exact match with its items. (And thats why you cannot mark utterance by hand and batch test it) You can try to create a simple entity instead of list and create a phrase list with the same name. I heard that this is taken by the algorithm and is more cognitive. Since we don't know the algorithm behind LUIS, this is always trial and error, keep up ;)